# Alternating turns between sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, events, socket.io

Lets say there's a div in the html file and the game is that each player gets to change the color but they could only change the color once the other player had his turn and they could alternate turns all day.

I've been having problems associating a player's turn with the socket they are on. I really want the following to happen when the first client goes to the website like localhost:8080 they should be greeted with "you are player1" and the 2nd visitor that goes to the website it should say "you are player 2". I would also like it so that when the page refreshes, the client looses connection and the other player automatically becomes 1. The one that was recently refreshed becomes 2 since that was the last connection made.

How would I be able to do this? I also want to plug that info so I could do something like what's in the click header.

I want to be able to do something like this.

```
var player; 
//player will be changed dynamically depending
$("div").on("click", function(){

    //if player == 1
    //player 1 cannot click again until player 2 from another socket clicks and the color has changed
    //change color

})



io.on("connection", function(socket){
    //Every time a person connects output their player number. Max 2 players
    //So on first connection == player 1
    //Second connection == player 2
    //If first connection refreshes page that browser / tab becomes player 2
    //  and the original player 2 become player 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I've assumed you are use client/server architecture not P2P)

On connection send a packet to the server indicating a join request:

```
socket.emit('joinReq', {}); //Send request to server
```

On the server side listen to this event and process it. You also need to track the current player count on the server

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('joinReq', function (data) {
        //update player count
        //Send player count over socket
        socket.emit('playerNumUpdate', { playerNum: <playernum variable> });
    });
});
```

Aaand finally receive and process this on the client

```
socket.on('playerNumUpdate', function (data) {
    <playernum variable> = data.playerNum; //Get the number sent by the server
});
```

Comment: I wrote another question with the problems that im experiencing now  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888709/updating-user-info-of-socket-on-connection-and-disconnect .please help