# updating user info of socket on connection and disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, events, socket.io

right now the code below produce the number that was created incrementally upon each connection. so one user goes to the page they get player 1. second user gets player 2. but when i close a tab in the browser and open another one I get "player 3" ....

1. I only want there to be 2 players max (right now it keeps incrementing)
2. if one closes or reloads the tab they become the second player and if the other tab which was part of the originall player if he was the second player becomes player 1

   ```
   $(document).ready( function(){

    var playernum;
       socket.on("connect", function(){

           socket.emit("joinReq", {});
       })
       socket.on("playerNumUpdate", function(data){
           playernum = data.playerNum;
               $(".playernum").html("player num is " + playernum)
       })
       socket.on("disconnect", function(){
           socket.emit("leaveReq", playernum);
           $(".playernum").html("player num is " + playernum)
       })
    });
   ```

server:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){
// socket.on("was clicked", function(data){
//  if(data == true){
//      socket.emit("return fromclick")
//  }
// })
socket.on("joinReq", function(data){
    playernum++
    socket.emit("playerNumUpdate", {playerNum : playernum})
})
socket.on("leaveReq", function(data){
    socket.emit("playerNumUpdate", {playerNum : playernum})
})
socket.on("disconnect", function(data){
    playernum = playernum--;
    socket.emit("playerNumUpdate", {playerNum : playernum})
})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

The disconnect event should have no (data)

```
socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    playernum = playernum--;
    socket.emit("playerNumUpdate", {playerNum : playernum})
});
```

If that doesn't work...

Try this:
[How can i handle Close event in Socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077719/how-can-i-handle-close-event-in-socket-io)

> On the client:
>
> ```
> var socket = io.connect(<your_url>, {
> 'sync disconnect on unload': true });
> ```

The issue seems to be that the disconnect isn't firing.